# In MapReduce framework why combiner is not guaranteed to execute?

Tags: java, mapreduce

I'm beginner to **MapReduce**. As per my understanding Combiner can be used to improve the performance by doing a aggregation at individual Map node.

My Question is: Will combiner gets executed on all the data set of Map? Or Running combiner step in **MapReduce** is optional?

Comment: added answer to your query, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we run `MapReduce` job on a large `dataset`, so Mapper generates large chunks of intermediate data and framework pass this intermediate data to the Reducer for further processing. This leads to enormous network congestion.

The `MapReduce` framework provides a function known as Combiner that plays a vital role in reducing network congestion. The `Combiner` is also called as Mini-reducer.

> Will `combiner` gets executed on all the data set of Map?

No, the `combiner` is executed at each buffer spill. Please note that a buffer spill can occur multiple time even in a single map phase.

> Or Running `combiner` step in `MapReduce` is optional?

Adding a `combiner` to the job is optional. It means if you do not add a `combiner`, the framework

1) **would not complain**

2) **would not explicitly add any default combiner.**

Now coming to execution - By default `combiner` is optional and `mapreduce` framework does not guarantee to execute the `combiner` given to the job.

Comment: Thanks gyan. Nice explanation.